# insert into statment error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ms-access

I've been trying to insert a specific data to my database (in my case it is Microsoft Access),
this is the following code I wrote using c#:

```
string sql = "Insert into Orders(User,PID,PName,Price,Amount)" +
             " values('" + od.User + "','" + od.Pid + "','" + 
             od.Pname + "','" + od.Price + "','" + od.Amount + "')";
```

now I assume the form I wrote is perfectly fine , isnt it?
the error I get is:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: Is it possible any of your values have single quotes in them?

Comment: What's the source of `od`? Are all those columns strings in the database table? On the first question, if it's a user, you could have Sql Injection vulnerabilities. Look into parameterized queries either way, because that would also deal with embedded single quotes in the inputs, as @Mike considers. On the second, if some of those columns are numeric, you would have data type issues.

Comment: why don't you use @Parameters when creating the Insert query then use the `command.Parameters.AddWithValues(@paramname, paramvalue);`

Comment: Well if he doesn't understand then I would be more than happy to post an answer as an example

Comment: I think you should, then I will be happy to up vote you =)

Comment: od is an object from class called Users, this line was written  in a function that its purpose to insert the mentioned values. if it is necassary I can paste the whole code.

Comment: lolol the answer that I posted should give him a better example on how to use `Parameters.AddWithValue()` method opposed to the answers where others have just posted a snippet of an answer and then saying `here you will need to add your parameters to your command`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User` is a [reserved keyword](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx). Put brackets around it to specify that you want to use it as an identifier, not a command:

```
string sql = "Insert into Orders([User],PID,PName,Price,Amount)" +
         " values('" + od.User + "','" + od.Pid + "','" + 
         od.Pname + "','" + od.Price + "','" + od.Amount + "')";
```

This should solve your immediate problem. Using a parameterised query (as several has suggested) is good to avoid future problems also.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code so you use a parameterized command:

```
string sql = "Insert into Orders([User],PID,PName,Price,Amount) values(@user, @pid, @pname, @price, @amount)";

..here you will need to add your parameters to your command
```

This both avoids SQL injection attacks and prevents errors with unescaped characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that you can follow I have pasted a copy from something I just wrote 
you may want to follow this for future references pay attention to how the `Parameters.AddWithValue()` method is being used instead of building the string query string with `Quoted` values

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        con.Open();
        string Sql = "INSERT INTO Uyeleri (dID, FullName, Address, Mobile, Email, Comments ) " + 
                     "VALUES (@id, @name, @address, @mobile, @email, @comments");
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtdID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtAdiSoyadi.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", txtMobile.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", txtComments.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Important note to OP: the values are added to `cmd.Parameters` in the exact same order in which they are used in your query.

Comment: Yes I am aware he wanted an example Brad so he could see how to do Parameterized Query..

Comment: yeah, and it's a great example (got my vote) I also thought he should know the order thing because it tripped me up the first time I used this kind of procedure.